# OnRowEdit throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable, classcastexception

I have a row editable primefaces datatable. The edit event momently looks like this

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
           Object newValue = (Spiel)event.getObject();
           System.out.println("Event Object");
           System.out.println(((Spiel)event.getObject()).getSid());
         }
```

The problem is that i still get java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to klassen.Spiel

The class Spiel

```
public class Spiel  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int sid;
     private int mid1, mid2;
     private Mannschaft gast;
     private Mannschaft heim;
     private String heimname;
     private String gastname; 
     private String tipp;
     private String endstand;
     private Date spielzeit;


     private Set<Wette> wettes = new HashSet<Wette>(0);

    public Spiel() {

    }


    public Spiel(int sid, Mannschaft heim, Mannschaft gast, Date spielzeit) {
        this.sid = sid;
        this.heim = heim;
        this.gast = gast;
        this.spielzeit = spielzeit;
    }

    public Spiel(int sid, int mid1, int mid2) {
        this.sid = sid;
        this.mid1 = mid1;
        this.mid2 = mid2;
    }
/* ... some other code */
```

The datatable get the data values via the following two methods:

```
//controller
    public DataModel getSpieleKomplett(){



      if(spielListeKomplett==null){
            spielListeKomplett = new ListDataModel(helperSpiele.getSpieleKomplett());
        }
        return spielListeKomplett;
    }

//helper    
public List getSpieleKomplett(){

       List spielListKomplett = null;

        try {

            if(session.isOpen()==false){
                session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            }
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM spiel");
            spielListKomplett = q.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            if(session.isOpen()==true){session.close();}       
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return spielListKomplett;
    }
```

My question is what should i do to cast the event.getObject so that i can access the values in the object via the getter methods?
Or is there another way to get the values from the object?

Thanks in advance.

complete code is here: https://github.com/tippspiel/em2016

Comment: If you know that the event is a Spiel object why not `Spiel newValue = (Spiel)event.getObject();` instead of `Object newValue = (Spiel)event.getObject();` ?

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i still get ClassCastException... does this may effect beacause of the usage of an SQLquery instead an HQL one? the problem is i need the sql one beacause the hql do not return some lines with null values...

Comment: Are you sure that the entity returned by rowedit is Spiel ?

Comment: iam not sure but i don't know how to do this without casting? i only want to have the values of the edit row to save these to the db. may there is another way to realize that? if you know please explain :)